# Fetching a whole row from a database table

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating this league of legends site and in a database I've got tables with each champion's name, position and spell names.  I'm wondering how I can access the entire row for just one specific champion.

The Table is built up like following:

```
TABLE `champions` (
`Champion_Name` TEXT NULL,
`Champion_Positions` TEXT NULL,
`Spell_Passive` TEXT NULL,
`Spell_1` TEXT NULL,
`Spell_2` TEXT NULL,
`Spell_3` TEXT NULL,
`Spell_Ultimate` TEXT NULL
)
```

And I chose what champion to fetch with `$_get`, so how do I make PHP search through the database table and include the entire row that contains the corresponding champion's name?

I have looked online but couldn't find a way that I understood or that I thought would work for me.

Comment: i have read about that already.. but i didnt quite get how to make the following work, is it really that bad when someone ask qbout something they didnt understand? yeez....<.< @Aleks G

Comment: i just love how people downvote questions like this without even telling why or giving anything constructive about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have an active `$_SESSION` with a username. Just search through your database via your API.

MySQLI:

```
$ChampName = $_GET['ChampionName'];
$Query = $Conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM champions WHERE `Champion_Name`=?");
$Query->bind_param('s',$ChampName);
$Query->execute();
$Results = $Query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you want more help apart from this.. You will have to show some code on what you have tried.

You might want to look into mysqli __construct on php.net

and do not use mysql_* functions.

Comment: hmm i suppose i should read up on mysqli functions then, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I assume the MySQLI answer will work great but here is a PHP MySQL version if you want to use it; for me this formatting always naturally made more sense so just in-case you are the same way here it is:

```
<?php
$ChampName = $_GET['ChampionName'];
//all your db conneciton stuff
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM champions Where Champion_name='" . $ChampName . "'");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $data['Champion_Name'] . '<br>';
echo $data['Champion_Positions'] . '<br>';
echo $data['Spell_Passive'] . '<br>';
/// etc...
?>
```

Comment: MySQL_* Should not be used within new code; as MySQL_* Is going through the depreciation process and will be removed from future php revisions